# Sanity Check - Cast Icon in Android Emulator

Tags: android, casting, android-emulator, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

After a period of distraction I return to my app in Android Studio, update everything, and embark upon fixing a chromecast issue ([here if interested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135819/chromecast-metadata)). What happened to the cast icon in the emulator? Am I losing it? I can't seem to find any reference to this problem so perhaps I am and perhaps I imagined it ever existed...

Answer (score 1):

Emulator is not connected to same wifi network as your chrome cast. thus, cast button doesn't show up in emulator